# Source of various versions of Haamek Davar

Tags: history, publications, haamek-davar

There are commonly used versions of *Chumash Haamek Davar* in which the respective *Haamek Davar* commentaries differ widely from one another. I mean that the differences are not a word here and a letter there but entire swaths of text — often a list of examples or a tangent — that are present or absent.

How did it happen that such widely differing versions are in the market? Did the author himself publish differing versions at different times? Or did he not publish at all, and these were taken from different manuscripts — and by whom and when and why? Or what?

Comment: Can you link/paste an example? Do the publishers of the versions give any manuscript information?

Comment: I'll try to include an example when I both have time and am near copies of the _sefer_, which is rarely. I'll then also look for manuscript info, though at least one version includes no such info. _B'li neder_.